# WSO2 Endpoint Basic Authentication

Tags: authentication, wso2, endpoint, wso2-esb

I am trying to add a new Endpoint to my local WSO2 ESB server instance.
The problem that I am facing is that if you try to browse my wsdl url in any browser, a Basic Authentication popup is prompted to be filled.

This means that when I try to add my endpoint through WSO2 ESB Carbon Administrative Console and I provide my wsdl uri, I am retrieving a "Unable to establish connection" message.

I think that this is caused because I have not found any way to provide these Basic Authentication credentials (user and password) to retrieve the endpoint.
All other examples that I have found are related to provide credentials when invoking the service but not when trying to retrieve wsdl in order to create endpoint.

Is there any way make this possible in WSO2 ESB?
Could it be possible to make a workarounf with Endpoint properties that are available through Create WSDL Endoint wizard?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's an option in WSO2 ESB to specify the wsdl inline.

So what you can do is authenticate in the browser download the wsdl. Then log in in the ESB to create your service and when asked to specify the wsdl you can give the downloaded file. Then only thing you need to do it set up the basic authentication in the ESB service.